# Bash Script - If always printing else

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script in bash to check if my rdiff-backup has run today, but my second `if` is not working.

```
rdiff() {

#Get day
date=$(date +%d)

x=0

#Treat day
if [ "$date" -le "09" ]; then
        date=$(date +%d | cut -c2)
else
        date=$(date +%d)
fi

#Run rdiff to check if it has run today and return 0 or 1
output="$(rdiff-backup -l folder/b/1_backup | grep " $date "; echo $?)"

#Echo output for testing only
echo "${output}"

#If true, x++
if [ "$output" == "0" ]; then
x=$((x+1))
printf $x"\n"
printf true"\n"

#If false, prints false
elif [ "$output" == "1" ]; then
printf false"\n"

#If anything else, do nothing
else
echo ???
fi

}
rdiff
exit 0
```

It's always printing my `else`.
What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, I'm new to bash scripting.

Bash version: 
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(0)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd11.1).

Comment: What is the value of `$output`? If you print it with quotes around, is it still what you expect?

Comment: You don't need a command substitution. Run `rdiff-backup`, then immediately save the value of `$?` with something like `status=$?`.

Comment: You mean echo "${output}"? It prints 0 (zero), which it should be.
If I make my rdiff-backup command give me something that doesn't exist, it prints 1, which means false.
I think the problem is in my second if, but I'm not sure.
Btw, nice nickname.

Comment: Side note - you may want to consider replacing `grep " $date"; echo $?)` with `grep -c " $date")`.  The "-c" flag gives you the count of how many matches were found.

Comment: @MateusScheper It only appears to print `0`. Try it with `echo "===${output}==="` so that you can see when the value begins and ends

Comment: `declare -p output` is the better way to see what a variable contains

Comment: `output` contains the output of `grep` *and* the exit status.

Comment: @thatotherguy It's printing something else too. Thank you, Sir.
Now the problem is that I only want it to output 0 or 1, not the rdiff part.
This is how it's printing: ===Current mirror: Fri Aug  3 00:01:05 2018
0===
Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, if you were really running with `sh`, not `bash`, then `[ "$foo" == "$bar" ]` would always be false because `==` isn't a valid string comparison operator in POSIX sh. Use `=` instead to be portable.

Comment: Anyhow, to isolate the exact problem, run `bash -x yourscript` to log each line before it's run; that way you can see the values actually being tested.

Comment: ...and as an aside, `printf` format strings should be constant unless you know what you're doing and have a very specific reason to do anything contrary. Use `printf '%s\n' "$x"`, to keep the data you want to print out-of-band from the format string.

Comment: I'm going with grep -q. It worked. 
Thank you to everybody and thank you for the tips, too!

Comment: This "Strings are equal when printed but comparison fails" problem keeps coming up under bash and other tags. Does anyone want to make a canonical faq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your variable contains the date in addition to the exit code.

You can either get rid of the grep output with `grep -q`:

```
output="$(rdiff-backup -l folder/b/1_backup | grep -q " $date "; echo $?)"
```

or more canonically, just test the exit code directly:

```
if rdiff-backup -l folder/b/1_backup | grep -q " $date "
then
  echo "Already done"
else
  echo "No match for $date"
fi
```